# Memory errors in python 2.7 when saving .pdf files

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf, matplotlib

I recently updated my old default python install from 2.6 to 2.7 through anaconda. And now I seem to be getting memory errors whenever I try to save the output of codes as .pdfs. The code does still work if trying to save in other formats, e.g. png.

This was not a problem on my old install, and I haven't changed anything else, so I'm a little stuck on what the problem could be. Here's an example of the error output I get:

- glibc detected * python: double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000002e8da30 ***

/home/astro/phrmat/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x77958)[0x7f45a35fe958]

```
======= Memory map: ======== 
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:47 19995434 /home/astro/phrmat/anaconda/bin/python2.7 
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:47 19995434 /home/astro/phrmat/anaconda/bin/python2.7 
00601000-03104000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [heap] 
7f4580000000-7f4580021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4580021000-7f4584000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f45855a6000-7f4586626000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4586626000-7f4586666000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f4586666000-7f4586695000 r-xp 00000000 00:47 17867391 /home/astro/phrmat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ttconv.so
7f4586695000-7f4586894000 ---p 0002f000 00:47 17867391 /home/astro/phrmat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ttconv.so 
7f4586894000-7f4586897000 rw-p 0002e000 00:47 17867391 /home/astro/phrmat/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ttconv.so
```

Any suggestions appreciated

---

SOLVED

---

following this thread, this was a known bug in Anaconda, updating anaconda and the libpng library fixed the problem.

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/HH8W4b7kLpc

conda update freetype

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that in systems where a library was linked against one version of `glibc`, and then moved to a system with a different `glibc` version.

Make sure to re-compile / update all the libraries you use in your PDF thing.